# link a common library with multiple sub-project

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I am a autotools newbie and have a source tree like the following:

```
src/
    ProgA/... and Makefile.am
    ProgB/... and Makefile.am
    ProgC/... and Makefile.am
    ...
```

All sub-projects make use of a common library, say libcommon and specified individually within each Makefile.am:

```
progA_LDADD = $(libcommon_LIBS)
```

Note that `$(libcommon_LIBS)` is defined by `PKG_CHECK_MODULE`. This works.

Is there a way to specify this in a higher-level and apply to all subproject?
I have tried to have a `src/common.mk`, and include it at each sub-project. Within the common.mk, I tried:

```
AM_LDFLAGS = $(libcommon_LIBS)
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never pass libraries to `AM_LDFLAGS` or, generally speaking, to `LDFLAGS` variables. The link editor arguments are positional and they will change meaning depending on which order you pass them to it.

You should be able to use `AM_LIBADD` and `AM_LDADD` for that, though.

On the other hand, consider using [non-recursive automake](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html), especially if you start importing `common.mk` and the like.